# Borg design with new-style classes

Tags: python

I came across the [Borg design](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/) and thought it would fit well with what I'm doing, however I'm getting a `DeprecationWarning` when using it (I'm using Python 2.6 currently, but will move to a newer version soon).

The new-style version found in the comments is:

```
class Borg(object):
    _state = {}
    def __new__(cls, *p, **k):
        self = object.__new__(cls, *p, **k)
        self.__dict__ = cls._state
        return self
```

However, when creating an instance with arguments gives the `DepricationWarning`:

```
DepricationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Is there a way to use the Borg design without using `object.__new__()` with arguments?

Comment: "thought it would fit well with what I'm doing"?  Why?  What purpose do you have for this?  99% of the time you can use a module global more simply.

Comment: A singleton is nothing more than a way of creating a global variable that is accessed as if you are creating a new instance of a class, in order to confuse other developers (out yourself later on) into introducing bugs into your software. I'd never heard of Borg before, but it appears to be the same only more so. Just define your class, and instantiate it into a module global directly after. All references to the global will share state. Magic!

Comment: I am extending a class (that isn't mine) for a project that can only ever be allowed to have one of that class. Doing some research, I stumbled upon the link in the question and figured I'd give it a try instead of a Singleton. Honestly, I didn't think of using a module as a "singleton". Would this be easier to do than using Borg?

Comment: Usually, "there can be only one" actually means "we want the whole program to share the same one". e.g. if I have a class representing my application config, I want the whole application to share the same one. But it doesn't actually cause any problems if the class is instantiated again and used privately somewhere. All you need to do is replace in the docs "this class is for global config; it is a singleton" with "this global variable holds the global config; it is an instance of this class". And then you avoid wasting time writing tricky code to make multiple instances behave a bit like one.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the advice! The class that I'm extending is the API to some database software. It complains if a single user tries to gain access from more than one instance, so I was trying to avoid that in the future. I suppose, though, that it is not impossible for a need to have multiple users logged in at once. I'll go with the module global instead.

Comment: It's also in general impossible in Python to absolutely prevent other programmers doing anything they want with your stuff. The same flexibility that make it possible to set up obstacles *also* makes it possible to get around them. If something has to be used a particular way, your best bet is documentation, naming conventions, and trusting your fellow developers. If the class shouldn't be used to instantiate, you can always try giving it a name with a leading underscore; this usually scares Python programmers into at least reading the docs and thinking about it before they use it.

Comment: @Ben, haha, this is true! I've been scared away by underscores before! I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to pass the arguments to `__new__`, they will get passed to `__init__` automatically. `object.__new__` doesn't use those arguments anyway. Here's what [the man himself](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/076854.html) says on the matter:

> There's no point in calling object.__new__() with more than a class
>   parameter, and any code that did so was just dumping those args into a
>   black hole.

So just do this instead:

```
class Borg(object):
    _state = {}
    def __new__(cls, *p, **k):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.__dict__ = cls._state
        return self

    def __init__(self, foo):
        print(foo)
```

Test it:

```
>>> import borg
>>> b = borg.Borg(foo='bar')
bar
```

(Tested with 2.7 only, assuming it works with 2.6 as well.)

Comment: The `super` call relies for correctness on `object ` being next in the MRO (otherwise you should be passing those arguments on). So IMHO it's better to be explicit about it and just call `object` directly.

Comment: @Ben, that's a good point. If we're not passing on the arguments there is probably little point in calling anything other than `object.__new__`. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.