# Why is this Python Borg / Singleton pattern working

Tags: python, singleton

i just stumbled around the net and found these interesting code snipped:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/

```
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
    # and whatever else you want in your class -- that's all!
```

I understand what a singleton is but i don't understand that particular code snipped.
Could you explain me how/where "__shared_state" is even changed at all?

I tried it in ipython:

```
In [1]: class Borg:
   ...:         __shared_state = {}
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:             self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
   ...:     # and whatever else you want in your class -- that's all!
   ...: 
In [2]: b1 = Borg()
In [3]: b2 = Borg()
In [4]: b1.foo="123"
In [5]: b2.foo
Out[5]: '123'
In [6]:
```

but cannot fully understand how this could happen.

Comment: This version doesn't work with new-style classes -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992241/borg-design-with-new-style-classes for discussion.

Comment: Also, it's bad style because `id(b1)` will be different from `id(b2)`, and `b1 is b2` will give `False`. A simple and solid way that works with both old and new style classes is by declaring a normal class `Foo` and then right after the class definition doing `Foo = Foo()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the <s>class's</s> instance's `__dict__` is set equal to the `__share_state` dict. They point to the *same object*. (`Classname.__dict__` holds all of the class attributes)

When you do:

```
b1.foo = "123"
```

You're modifying the `dict` that both `b1.__dict__` and `Borg.__shared_state` refer to.

Comment: Incidentally, can anyone explain *why* you would want to use a pattern like this? I would think that in most situations (in every situation I can think of) you would just hold multiple references to the *same* instance, without all this hackery.

Comment: It's short, it does what i want and i dont understand it at first.
Now i get it, when i equals a dic i only copy an reference, this was not clear to me. Thank you for this Lesson!

Comment: @DavidosKrausos: No problem. No judgement on my part, I'm just genuinely curious what sort of thing you would use this pattern for.

Comment: @DavidosKrausos: Actually, now I get it. The answer was in [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318406/why-is-the-borg-pattern-better-than-the-singleton-pattern-in-python).

Comment: It's not the class's `__dict__` but the instance's `__dict__`'s which are set equal to the `__shared_state` dict.

Answer (score 3):

The `__init__` method, which is called after instantiating any object, replaces the `__dict__` attribute of the newly created object with the class attribute `__shared_state`.

`a.__dict__`, `b.__dict__` and `Borg._Borg__shared_state` are all the same object. Note that we have to add the implicit prefix `_Borg` when accessing private attribute from outside the class.

```
In [89]: a.__dict__ is b.__dict__ is Borg._Borg__shared_state
Out[89]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

The instances are separate objects, but by setting their `__dict__` attributes to the same value, the instances have the *same* attribute dictionary. Python uses the attribute dictionary to store all attributes on an object, so in effect the two instances will behave the same way because every change to their attributes is made to the shared attribute dictionary.

However, the objects will still compare unequal if using `is` to test equality (shallow equality), since they are still distinct instances (much like individual Borg drones, which share their thoughts but are physically distinct).