# PyQt5 GUI, sharing data between multiple models

Tags: python, pyqt5

**INTRO**

Hello, I am in the process of making an interactive GUI for displaying multiple data sets on multiple plots.

The idea is that you can add and remove data sets and graphs, and then chose on which graph you want to display witch data set or maybe even one data sets on multiple graphs...

[image: GUI]

In MainModel I create and delete SignalModel-s (where data sets are stored and processed) and GraphModel-s and store them in *graphs* and *signals* lists, as you can see below.

MainModel:

```
class MainModel(QObject):
  // signals
  
  //
  @property
  def signals(self):
    return self._signals

  def signals_append(self, value: SignalModel):
    value.on_delete.connect(self.signals_delete)
    self._signals.append(value)

  def signals_delete(self, value: SignalModel):
    self._signals.remove(value)

  @property
  def graphs(self):
    return self._graphs

  def graphs_append(self, value: GraphModel):
    value.on_delete.connect(self.graphs_delete)
    self._graphs.append(value)

  def graphs_delete(self, value: GraphModel):
    print("Deleting: ", str(value))
    self._graphs.remove(value)
    value.deleteLater()
    print(self._graphs)

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self._signals = []
    self._graphs = []
```

In SignaModel

Signalmodel:

```
class SignalBarModel(QObject):

  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._name

  @name.setter
  def name(self, value: str):
    self._name = value
    self.on_name_changed.emit(value)

  @property
  def color(self):
    return self._color

  @color.setter
  def color(self, value):
    self._color = value
    self.on_color_changed.emit(value)

  @property
  def input_data(self):
    return self._input_data

  @input_data.setter
  def input_data(self, value: list):
    self._input_data = value
    # call function for calculating output_data

  @property
  def output_data(self):
    return self._output_data

  @output_data.setter
  def output_data(self, value):
    self._output_data = value
    self.on_output_data_changed.emit(value)

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self._name = "Signal"
    self._color = "WHITE"

    self._input_data = []

    self._output_data = []
```

**PROBLEM**

I am not sure what will be the best way to pass and store data in GraphModel, as it can be data from one, two or hundreds of SignalModel-s, and they can be added or removed during program execution.

GraphModel:

```
class GraphModel(QObject):
  // Signals

  //
  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._name

  @name.setter
  def name(self, value: str):
    self._name = value
    self.on_name_changed.emit(value)

  @property
  def plot(self):
    return self._plot

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self._name = "Graph"
    self._plot = PlotWidget()

    // Data points from multiple signals or SignalModel??
    self._data = []
    self._signals = [] : SignalModel

  def delete(self):
    self.on_delete.emit(self)
    self.on_delete_views.emit()
```

I tried connecting pyqtSignal from SignalModel-s to update data in GraphModel but, than I would somhow need to know data sets from other SignalModels. So I tried to make that when one SignalModel data changes all SignalModels will emit its pyqtSignal, but it resulted in one big mess.

Then I was thinking of two more ways of how to solve this but didn't have the time to test it out and would like to get more opinions before jumping on it...

1.)
Introducing IDs to SignalModels, and storing on which IDs is GraphModel connected and store catched data under corect ID. (I just don't feel like doing this, but I will if it will be necessary).

2.)
To send pyqtSignal(SignalModel) every time data changes or you want to disconect signal from graph. I am not sure how this will efect performance if there will be lots of data points in one signla.

Would like to hear it from you as I don't have that deep knowledge of GUI design and pyqt5 in general and I probably overlooked a more efficient solution.

**QUESTION**

How was it intended to share data between multiple models using pyqt5?

Is it recommended to share large (whole models) data classes using pyqtSignals?

Comment: having your models communicate through signals means your business logic will be tied to the eventloop (view), which is (as you have already seen) very bad, instead you want the controller to communicate with some python class that handle your models which are also python classes in a pythonic way, no QT involved, then update the GUI accordingly.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I see what you mean, but I don't know how this python class that handles model should look, do you have any key words so I can do more research or an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237186/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-widgets-with-pyqt here they call for a Singleton Class, but no vote or accepted